# Polymer Drawer Panel and Firefox don't seem to mix, how could display be improved?

Tags: firefox, dart, polymer, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I'm using a drawer-panel from the core_elements, to display a side menu and a main part.

```
<core-drawer-panel>

  <div drawer>
    <core-menu selected="0"> 
        <core-item icon="favorite" label="Menu Label"> <a href="#/myview" target="_self"></a></core-item>
    </core-menu>
     </div>

  <div main>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>

</core-drawer-panel>
```

This work perfectly using both Dartium and Chrome, but in Firefox the views connected to ng-view get messed up. Removing the core-item helps to recover the layout in Firefox, but having a menu is convenient. Replacing the menu with a standard `<ul>` helps until you put a link in the list.

The following works fine:

```
<core-drawer-panel>    
  <ul class="menu">
     <li><core-icon icon="favorite"></core-icon>Menu Label</li>
  </ul>
...
```

While adding a link anywhere in the drawer-panel messes up the layout in Firefox.

Why would this behavior occur? Adding a `ng-click` to the item results in the same layout problems, as when using a link.